# Get battery level and state in Android

Tags: java, android, battery

How can I get battery level and state (plugged in, discharging, charging, etc)? I researched the developer docs and I found a BatteryManager class. But it doesn't contain any methods, just constants. How do I even use it?

Comment: After some MORE researching, I found BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

[Tutorial For Android](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721185308/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com:80/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html) has a code sample that explains how to get battery information.

To sum it up, a broadcast receiver for the `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` intent is set up dynamically, because it can not be received through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with `Context.registerReceiver()`.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private TextView batteryTxt;
  private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
      int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
      float batteryPct = level * 100 / (float)scale;
      batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(batteryPct) + "%");
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    batteryTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  }
}
```

Comment: About Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED: This is a sticky broadcast containing the charging state, level, and other information about the battery. You can not receive this through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

Comment: @classAndroid well, yes, that's explicitely stated in the answer.

Comment: Yes @SirDarius, just letting others know about it. I upvoted your answer first and put this comment when I found it out. :)

Comment: don't forget to unRegisterReceiver onPause or onDestroy.

Comment: Cannot able to instaialise battery manager with new Keywork , Why sir ?

Comment: EXTRA_LEVEL is not exact.  You need to scale it.  See [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#CurrentLevel) for detail.

Comment: there is no state, only level, why it was accept if it's not a full answer?

Comment: @user924 if you think you can improve this answer, please feel free to do so. If the Original Poster accepted this answer, I believe they were satisfied with the contents.

Comment: from author question __Get battery level and **state** in Android__. Is there any code to get state in your code? no :) Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59025376/7767664

Comment: Dont we need any permissions for it?

Comment: BroadcastReceiver is an abstract class..

Comment: @Troughy yes it is. Do you know it's possible to extend an abstract class anonymously in Java? It is what is done here, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/10479045/393701.

Answer (score 156):

Since `SDK 21` `LOLLIPOP` it is possible to use the following to get current battery level as a percentage:

```
BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
int batLevel = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
```

Read [BatteryManager  |  Android Developers - BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)

Comment: did you forgot about state?)

Answer (score 102):

Based on [official android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#MonitorLevel), you can use this method in a Helper or Util class to get current battery percentage:

**Java version:**

```
public static int getBatteryPercentage(Context context) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {

         BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
         return bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);

    } else {

         IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
         Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, iFilter);

         int level = batteryStatus != null ? batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) : -1;
         int scale = batteryStatus != null ? batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1) : -1;

         double batteryPct = level / (double) scale;

         return (int) (batteryPct * 100);
   }
}
```

**Kotlin version:**

```
fun getBatteryPercentage(context: Context): Int {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        val bm = context.getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
        bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
    
    } else {
        val iFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
        val batteryStatus: Intent = context.registerReceiver(null, iFilter)
        val level = batteryStatus?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1)
        val scale = batteryStatus?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)
        val batteryPct = level / scale.toDouble()
        (batteryPct * 100).toInt()
    }
}
```

Comment: one mistake in official docs, you must use double instead float 
int level = batteryStatus != null ? batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) : -1;
int scale = batteryStatus != null ? batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1) : -1;
double batteryPct = (double) level / (double) scale;
int percent = (int) (batteryPct * 100D);

Comment: @user2212515, would you mind edit my answer based on the official docs?

Comment: @Ryan, I edited my answer to support android v21 and later. Please check it out.

Comment: did you forgot about state?)

Answer (score 16):

You don't have to register an actual BroadcastReceiver as Android's BatteryManager is using a sticky Intent:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;

return (int)(batteryPct*100);
```

This is from the official docs over at https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html.

Answer (score 10):

Other answers didn't mention how to [access battery status](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#DetermineChargeState) (chraging or not).

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

// Are we charging / charged?
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                     status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

// How are we charging?
int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
```

Comment: Finally, someone who answered about battery status

Answer (score 7):

You can use this to get remaining charged in percentage.

```
private void batteryLevel() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                batterLevel.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

try this function no need permisson or any reciver

```
void getBattery_percentage()
{
      IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
      Intent batteryStatus = getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
      int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
      int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
      float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
      float p = batteryPct * 100;

      Log.d("Battery percentage",String.valueOf(Math.round(p)));
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

To check battery percentage we use **BatteryManager**, the following method will return battery percentage.

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/android-useful-methods-and-functions/#5method)**

```
public static float getBatteryLevel(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null,
            new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int batteryLevel = -1;
    int batteryScale = 1;
    if (batteryStatus != null) {
        batteryLevel = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, batteryLevel);
        batteryScale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, batteryScale);
    }
    return batteryLevel / (float) batteryScale * 100;
}
```

Comment: hey I used this and sometimes the result is is 89 sometimes its 00.89 its moving the decimals whats happening

Answer (score 3):

one mistake in official docs, you must use double instead float. Because 0.53F * 100F = 52F

```
int level = batteryStatus != null ? 
batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) : -1; int scale = 
batteryStatus != null ? batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1) : -1; 
double batteryPct = (double) level / (double) scale; int percent = (int) (batteryPct * 100D);
```

Comment: Isn't that 0.53F -> 52F mistake caused by casting final value to int (thus stripping any decimal 0.x value from it), instead of using Math.round()?

Answer (score 2):

get battery level in Android-Kotlin:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        registerReceiver(this.broadcastReceiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
    }

    private val broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent) {
            
            val level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0)
            binding.txtShowBatteryLevel.text = "Battery level: %$level"
            
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void batteryLevel() {
        BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
                int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
                int level = -1;
                if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                    level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
                }
                mBtn.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
            }
        };
        IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on these great answers I modified the getBatteryPercentage. Btw I used "Carlson Notation" code formatting because it's just plain easier to read fast.

```
public static String getBatteryPercentage(Context context)
{
    String bstatus       = "isChrg=false usbChrg=false acChrg=false wlChrg=false 0% t=70°F";
    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, iFilter);
    int status           = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging   = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                           status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
    int level            = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale            = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
    float batteryPct     = level * 100 / (float)scale;
    //How are we charging?
    int chargePlug       = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge    = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge     = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;
    boolean wlCharge     = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_WIRELESS;
    int temp             = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
    float tempTwo        = ((float) temp) / 10;
    double d             = CelsiusToFahrenheit(tempTwo);
    bstatus              = String.format(Locale.US, "isChrg=%b usbChrg=%b acChrg=%b wlChrg=%b %.0f%% t=%.2f°F",
                           isCharging,
                           usbCharge,
                           acCharge,
                           wlCharge,
                           batteryPct,
                           d);
    return bstatus;
}
```