# Unregistering Android Broadcast Receiver in onReceive throws "Receiver not registered"

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` for one time use.

I'm registering it in an Activity. I can't put the `unregisterReceiver()` in `onPause` because it has to stay running even when the activity is paused or destroyed.

I want the BroadcastReceiver to unregister itself when it is done, something like this:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           // do some code..
           context.unregisterReceiver(this)
        }
}
```

But it causes an Exception: `Receiver not registered.`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A `BroadcastReceiver` only exists during the execution of its `onReceive()` method. So, *this* evaluates to a throw-away instance every time the broadcast is fired/received. See [Broadcast Receiver Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle). For dynamically registering/unregistering of `BroadcastReceiver`s, you have to remember the instance of your receiver in `onPause()` to register it again during `onResume()`.

Comment: A BroadcastReceiver object follows the same garbage collection rules as any other object.  There's no special "throw-away instance".  Referencing `this` in `onReceive` gives the same result a reference from when the object was created (try it).  The documentation is talking about the receiver's *process* being killed, not anything at the level of the receiver object.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question already has an answer But try this Code

This code is for **BatteryInfo**. And it did work.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
        Log.i("Battery", String.valueOf(level) + "%");
        arg0.unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
    }

};

//Below code is the Code which attaches the reciever put this code in which ever place you want. 

this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

Reference for Attaching [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android) / [Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721185308/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/getting-battery-information-on-android.html)

Comment: this did not work for me, it says it is not registered. i think original mBatInfoReceiver does not exist by the time onReceive is called

Comment: Why would this make any difference?

Answer (score 4):

Just add a method call to the Activity you registered it in, and in **that** method, unregister the receiver. That way you **know** its job has been done.

However, the receiver won't work if the activity is stopped or destroyed anyways. You'd have to  declare it in the manifest or else register it in a long-running service to keep it working outside of an activity's lifetime. As far as I know, you can't unregister a receiver declared in the manifest because you don't get the instance it's registered with. But the method call to the Service to unregister it should work.

If you just need a worker for one-time use, declare an exported IntentService in the manifest with the action you're broadcasting. That IntentService will be started when the intent is received and given the intent that started it, and then when it's done its job, it will stop on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem, actually, the correct answer is `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).unregisterReceiver(this);` but not `context.unregisterReceiver(this)`

Comment: Do you miss something in your answer? "but not `enter code here`". Please fix it

Comment: That did not work for me, I've posted another solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39748974/4221945)

Comment: This is not the correct answer. LocalBroadcastManager is a lightweight solution for broadcasts within an app. Not to be confused with ordinary IPC-capable broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unregistering the reciver from a Service/Activity? Maybe there is some issue if you call it from the reciever to unregister itself.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have already unregistered it elsewhere in your program, however unlikely this may sound. Maybe somewhere before your `context.unregisterReceiver`, but in the `onReceive` method you invoke an action, that results in unregeistering the receiver prior to reaching `context.unregisterReceiver`.

Just make sure you are unregistering the receiver from as less places as possible, preferably - exactly one.

Comment: But if I unregistered it already, how come it still gets to that point and runs the unregister method? It's not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is that you are trying to unregister the receiver from the *receiver's* context, instead of the context where it was originally registered.