# android - how to broadcast receiver is registered or not?

Tags: android

I am creating  broadcast receiver and calling from an activity. dynamically i want to check the broadcast receiver is registered or not so that i can unregister the broadcast receiver?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please check the link below for the answer. Their you can see a short nice answer:

[Unregistering Android Broadcast Receiver in onReceive throws "Receiver not registered"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957461/unregister-broadcast-receiver-android)

Answer (score 0):

have this code to enable and disable the broadcast receiver using package manager:
This code works like Toggle button.

```
int flag = (enabled ?
                    PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED :
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED);

            if(flag == 1)
                flag = 2;
            else
                flag = 1;

            Log.d("After Flag","::"+flag);

            ComponentName component = new ComponentName(StartActivity.this, SMSReceiver.class);

            getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, flag,PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Where enable is Boolean which I have saved as shared preference to know whether the last time my broadcast receiver was working or not.