# Android - How to destroy a BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, proximity, ondestroy

I have implemented a `BroadcastReceiver` (called `ProximityIntentReceiver`) in my Android app, but i have some annoying problems. In the `onCreate()` method of my `MainActivity` I call this function:

**addProximityAlert():**

```
private ProximityIntentReceiver proximityIntentReceiver;
private void addProximityAlert() {
    pendingIntentList = new HashMap<Integer, PendingIntent>();
    double latitude = 37.567072;
    double longitude = 14.273046;
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    locationManager.addProximityAlert(
            latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
            longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
            POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
            PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no                           expiration
            proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
    );
    pendingIntentList.put(1, proximityIntent);
    proximityIntentReceiver = new ProximityIntentReceiver();
    registerReceiver(proximityIntentReceiver, filter);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alert Added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is, instead, the onDestroy of my MainActivity:

**onDestroy():**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    if(proximityIntentReceiver!=null) {
        unregisterReceiver(proximityIntentReceiver);
        removeProximityAlert();

    }
}
```

**removeProximityAlert():**

```
private HashMap<Integer, PendingIntent> pendingIntentList;
private void removeProximityAlert () {

    Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, PendingIntent>> iterator = pendingIntentList.entrySet().iterator() ;
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<Integer, PendingIntent> pendingIntentMap = iterator.next();
        locationManager.removeProximityAlert(pendingIntentMap.getValue());
    }
}
```

Now if i change something on my `BroadcastReceiver` or in my `addProximityAlert()`, changes remain the same until I reboot the device. Why? I thought that by calling the `unregisterReceiver()` method was sufficient to remove the instance of the `BroadcastReceiver`...

What should I add to my code?

Comment: > _Now if i change something on my BroadcastReceiver or in my addProximityAlert, changes remain the same until i reboot the device._  Specifically, what are you changing and what do you expect to see?

Comment: For example if i change the POINT_RADIUS variable or something else...

Answer (score 2):

A `BroadcastReceiver` only exists during the execution of its `onReceive()` method. So, this evaluates to a throw-away instance every time the broadcast is fired/received. For dynamically registering/unregistering of `BroadcastReceiver`s, you have to remember the instance of your receiver in `onPause()` to register it again during `onResume()`.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

For an `Activity`:

In order to register your `BroadcastReceiver` from within your app, first, remove the `<receiver>` tag from your *AndroidManifest.xml* file. Then, call `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter)` in your `onResume()`. Use `unregisterReceiver(BroadcastReceiver receiver)` in your `onPause()` to unregister the `BroadcastReceiver`.

For a `Service`:

Remove the receiver tag from the manifest file. You can then register your `BroadcastReceiver` with the same method in the `onCreate()` and unregister in the `onDestroy()`.

Took Reference From: 1: [Unregister broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957461/unregister-broadcast-receiver-android) 2: [unregister receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439041/how-to-unregister-broadcastreceiver)

You can check [here](http://codetheory.in/android-broadcast-receivers/), which gives you more details about the working of `BroadcastReceiver`s.

Still not your problem is solved, please let me know.

Comment: So i have to remove the unregisterReceiver method from onDestroy and calling it in onPause? And i have to remove the registerReceiver from my addProximityAlert?

Comment: you should unregister it from onPause() method.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally pressed the Enter key before finishing the comment

Comment: its ok. You should need to unregister receiver form onPause() and need to register receiver from onResume().

Comment: I made these changes but the problem persist... If you restart the phone the receiver is called, otherwise nothing happens

Comment: What  happens if you have something like an importer object that's created in the onReceive() method, then importer.execute() is applied in a separate thread? Will onReceive() garbage collect the importer mid execution?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your constraints (POINT_RADIUS etc) are not being updated because you're retrieving your pending intent with flags '0':

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

`LocationManager.addProximityAlert()` takes the pending intent you give it and sets up a recurring alarm using the intent it contains. If you subsequently call `addProximityAlert()` with a PendingIntent that matches the previous one (according to `Intent.filterEquals()`), the alarm won't get updated, and your new constraints will not take effect.

To fix, you need to set the right flag so that the pending intent replaces the previous one.

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The flags are documented here (incidentally, I think '0' is undefined behaviour): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

NB, if `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` does not work, you may need `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` instead.