# Is it OK to unregister 'dynamic' BroadcastReceiver from receiver's own onReceive() method?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

That is,  I have this BroadcastReceiver I create on the fly to listen for one broadast, after which I want it to unregister itself.

I haven't found any sample code that does it this way, but neither have I found any rule in the android online docs that forbids this. But I cannot let it hang around for as long as the activity, and it is in an anonymous class anyway, so the containing class does not even know the variable name.

That is, the code looks something like this:

```
myInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intt) {
    // do some Notification when I get here
    nm.notify("I got here") // obvious pseudo code
    ctx.unregisterReceiver(myInfoReceiver);
} // end onReceive
ctx.registerReceiver),uInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(...));
}; // end BroadcastReceiver
```

But when I run this, Android complains when it calls unregister, insisting that the receiver is not there to unregister (I forget the exact wording, but it threw IllegalArgumentException).

I also tried modifying the code to check that the action in 'intt' is the same as expected -- but then it still executest onReceive but silently fails to unregister.

Comment: What goal do you want to achieve? I suppose, `BroadcastReceiver` may be wrong choice for your problem. If you want to do some operation once and you want to make it independent from activity life-cycle, consider using `IntentService` or `Service` with event bus (e.g. Otto).

Comment: I would not have used IntentService etc. because the larger system this is part of already has a broadcast intent representing precisely the information I want. Also, I don't need that much independence from lifecycle. I am already on the UI thread waiting for this intent, doing nothing but show a progress dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to your question is "yes". However...

...you need to call `unregisterReceiver()` on the same `Context` that you called `registerReceiver()` on. In the code you posted you are calling `unregisterReceiver()` on the `Context` passed in as an argument to `onReceive()`. This is not the same `Context` which is why you are getting the exception.

Comment: I have been suspicious of the context for some time now. Thanks for probiding certainty.

Comment: I'm facing this problem right now. Is there a good work around?

Comment: I've checked and context passed as a parameter is the same context on which I'm calling registerReceiver().

Comment: @GregorAžbe I don't understand the relevance of your comment to this answer. If you are having a problem, please open a new question and describe your problem.

Comment: @DavidWasser I just wanted to point out, that statement in last sentence of your answer were wrong in my case.

Comment: @GregorAžbe but you are having the same symptom as OP? In that case your situation is different and you should post a new question. Because if the `Context` is the same, you wouldn't be getting the error that OP was getting when trying to unregister.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply say YES, no problem at all.

I use it for a one-time location fix for example, and can be used in other logics too without me seeing any problem to it.

Plus I've seen it around many times.

Comment: I would have thought "no problem at all" too. But I get IllegalArgumentException. Any idea why? How can it not still be registered in its own onReceive() method?

Comment: Are you passing the correct receiver object while unregistering the receiver as I could see a mismatch in the above code you published

Comment: You just need to call this on the same `Context`. Use something like `MyActivity.this` for an `Activity` for example. Otherwise, post the stacktrace please.

Comment: I prefer to use application context in this case. It won't be null and it is consistent across Activity / Services

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various solutions, finally I am doing it that way:

Registering:

```
MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(sentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
```

SentReceiver:

```
public class SentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        context.getString(R.string.sms_envoye), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        context.getString(R.string.sms_defaillance_generique),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        context.getString(R.string.sms_pas_de_service),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        context.getString(R.string.sms_pas_de_pdu),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(context,
                        context.getString(R.string.sms_radio_desactivee),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
```

With MyApplication:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }        
}
```