# In Java, can anonymous classes extend another class?

Tags: java, class, nested, extend, anonymous

Code like:

```
protected Interface1 varClass1 = new Interface1() {
```

But I would also like that this anonymous nested class also extends the class `Base`, something like:

```
protected Interface1 varClass1 = new Interface1() extends Base {
....
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: @EranMedan - This question is specifically about doing both at the same time: extending a class while implementing an interface. The other question is about doing either one alone.

Comment: @DavidHarkness you are right, no more SO at 5am for me

Comment: To me, it feels like your intended anonymous class is a tad schizophrenic. Especially if it needs to interact with fields of the containing class. I strongly suggest you meditate on if what you really need is a slight redesign.

Answer (score 31):

An anonymous class can either implement exactly one interface *or* extend one class.

One workaround is to create a named class that extends `Base` and implements `Interface1`, and then use that as the base class for the anonymous class:

```
public abstract class Base1 extends Base implements Interface1 {}

...

protected Interface1 varClass1 = new Base1() {
   ...
```

Comment: +1, nice solution! Only thing I would add is that if you need to do this, then it is a hint that you are stretching beyond the intended use of anonymous classes and should perhaps consider full named inner classes instead.

Comment: To limit the scope of `Base1` you can even declare it inside the method, right before it is used.

Comment: @aioobe - Inside the *method?*

Comment: @DavidHarkness inside the body of the method you can declare a class: `class Hello {}`

Comment: @aix: Can the inheritance doing with the same when creating the object?

Comment: Note that you can declare Base1 within a method (remove the public) and that'd be interesting to declare it abstract. This way it'd look more like what the OP wants.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet - Funny, with anonymous classes I never needed to do this and so never tried. Cool. :)

Answer (score 3):

While it is not possible to both extend a class and implement an interface, what you probably what to do can be achieved using [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_%28programming%29).

Just create an instance of `Base` in the initializer of your anonymous class and use its methods from the methods you implement from `Interface1`.

**EDIT**: My answer assumes that you only want to inherit from `Base` because of its implementation, not because of its interface. This is a valid assumption given that the interface of `Base`is not visible after assigning the object to a `Interface1` variable. Therefore, I think it's better to use delegation here instead of creating a new class.