# get battery level on Android after specfic code

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to get the battery change after a certain code. I am using the following code but unfortunately with no luck. I am getting zeros any ideas please

on the on create a:

```
batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null,new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

private double batteryLevel() {
   int rawlevel = batteryIntent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
   double scale = batteryIntent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
   double level = -1;
   if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
       level = rawlevel / scale;

   }
return level;

 }
```

and on the onClick:

```
double startbatterylevel = batteryLevel();

//certain code

double estimatedbattery  =  startbatterylevel -  endbatterylevel ;
Estbatterylevel.setText("estimated battery"+estimatedbattery);
```

Comment: perhaps there was no change on the battery ?

Comment: How do you know that there should be ? taking time is not a viable hint/argument... there are lots of aspects that can take effect on battery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you wrote it, we don't know if the problem is in the battery level detection method or in the subtraction. What is the output of the `batteryLevel();` method? Is it accurate or always a default value?

You can try to adapt the example on this page: http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-sdk-get-device-battery-information/

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    ...
}

private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        Estbatterylevel.setText("estimated battery" + level);
    }
};
```

If it is still showing 0, maybe there are compatibility issues. Can you provide your device specifications and android version ?

Comment: i think no , could you kindly let me know how to do that ?

Comment: Android Version 2.3.6 - Samsung W GT-I8150

Answer (score 3):

see i found some of the links will help you

http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/androids-batterymanager-and-progressbar-two-for-one-tutorial/703

[Get battery level and state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)