# How can I display battery level via Images?

Tags: android

I want to show the battery level of phone using images and these images will change dynamically as battery level increases or decreases. Is their any specific API for this ? Any reference for this would be great..

Comment: You can just type "imageHeightPercent = batteryPercent"! Oh, wait, no that's not it. Maybe start with working out getting the battery level. This seems useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android

Comment: I acquired the level. But how can I make it show images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a Receiver in your class where you want to show battery level like

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
      batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");

      if(level > 90)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery9);
      else if(level > 80)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery8);
      else if(level > 70)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery7);
      else if(level > 60)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery6);
      else if(level > 50)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery5);
      else if(level > 35)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery4);
      else if(level > 20)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery3);
      else if(level > 5)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery2);
      else if(level > 2)
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery1);
      else 
        img_battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery0);

    }
};
```

and register the reciever in onCreate

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

don't forget to un-register it as well in onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

and img_battery would be the ImageView in which you are showing battery level, and batteryTxt would be the TextView which shows exact percentage.

Comment: if I add this sir, would this display battery level via image? And If I will use the smali file of this, i will use <com.blabla.battery ?

Comment: For making a separate file for this you will have to pass the context of the activity and make the respective calls in onDestroy and onCreate. R.drawable.battery9 .... R.drawable.battery0 are the images of battery representing the different battery levels.

Comment: im new to this things sir. How will I be able to start the java file? I choosed programming to be my hobby. I dont know so much things

Comment: do you have a facebook account sir? So we can talk more clearly?

Comment: Are there multiple activities in which you want to show battery level indicator?
facebook id 100007971587388

Comment: Please please please unregister in onPause and re-register in onResume!  Otherwise the Activity will keep waking up and doing stuff for no reason, even when it's not visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to custom a view for your battery life.A wrapper rect with a inner indicator rect. With different level of battery, you can draw the inner container with different width and color. Draw png is also approachable

Comment: how can I make from scratch? im new to these things