# checking battery level in background and notify when reach 7 percentage

Tags: android

Can I get a code for android app which run in background and continuously checks the battery percentage and notify me when battery level reaches to 7 percentage,
I tried its installing but not showing the app on screen.

Comment: what does mean of "showing the app on screen" ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get battery level and state in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Here we listen to a Intent (ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) and register a receiver when the intent is fired. In ActionScript, this is i believe is DispatchEvent, and we would call mBatInfoReceiver and get the current level of our battery life and put that int value to our textfield or TextView.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private TextView contentTxt;
  private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {
      int level = intent.getIntExtra("batterylevel", 7);
      contentText.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    contentText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.mspaceTxt);
    this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
    new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
  }
}
```