# how to set the value in custom notification textview

Tags: android, sdk, android-notifications

please help me to set the text in textview in custom notification

```
    private void startNotification()
 {
     String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, null, System.currentTimeMillis());
    RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.mynotification);
    mRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.appName, getResources().getText(0,"gfhf"));
    mBuilder.setContent(mRemoteViews);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, FlashLight.class);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentView = notificationView;
    notification.contentIntent = pendingNotificationIntent;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    Intent switchIntent = new Intent(this, switchButtonListener.class);
    PendingIntent pendingSwitchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, switchIntent, 0);
    notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.closeOnFlash,  pendingSwitchIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

}
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.RemoteViews.setTextViewText(int,
>   java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Please help me how to resolve this . how to set the value on textview in notification in android , Thanks in advance .

Comment: What exactly do you want ?? Do you want to create custom notification with your custom style textView ? For that create custom class and override DefaultNotificationFactory and create your own view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this:

```
private void startNotification() {

    int icon = R.drawable.icon_48;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon_48);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Notification Title/App Name");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "message");
    notification.contentView = contentView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

**custom_notification.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="10dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    style="Custom Notification Title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#336ba4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    style="Custom Notification Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#336ba4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how to put the value at run time after calculation . thanks amarbir i got the value but it display zero nit actual value

Comment: i want to set the battery current percentage  value in that textview .. in that i am able to fetch the value but when i place into this text view it display zero

Comment: have you checked that you are getting the battery percentage in your log or some where else?? textES.setText(String.format("%.1f",percentage) + "%");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android after that use sharedpreference to save it and get back to your Notification class.

Comment: is there any other way apart from sharedpreference to resolve this

Comment: then save it in your sharedpreference class and get it back when you want to and use textview.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");

Comment: yes if you are getting the battery status in the same class

Comment: ya we are getting that in same class .. then how do we do that

Comment: public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   boolean isPresent = intent.getBooleanExtra("present", false);
   String technology = intent.getStringExtra("technology");
   
   int plugged = intent.getIntExtra("plugged", -1);
   int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
   
   int rawlevel = intent.getIntExtra("level", -1);
   
   int level = 0;

   Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

   Log.i("BatteryLevel", bundle.toString());

   if (isPresent) {
    if (rawlevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
     level = (rawlevel * 100) / scale;
    }

Comment: where is your textview on which you are setting the battery status.

Comment: have you check the link which i added in the comment earlier.

Comment: contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Notification Title/App Name"); in this text view i need to pleace the battery  value

Comment: yes!! contentView.setTextViewText(String.valueOf(level) + "%");

Comment: i am doing in same way but it is showing zero value in this and  this The method setTextViewText(int, CharSequence) in the type RemoteViews is not applicable for the arguments (String)  error also

Comment: contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text,String.valueOf(level) + "%");

Comment: still not working then just put your code in https://gist.github.com/ and share your link!!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/551b4c2634e72830da1b8c533f28f9f8           getting zero in the textview

Comment: its same as level only .. i try with different values

Comment: Thanks  Amarbir Singh u really help me lot .. u saved me

Comment: If Working Fine Then Please Up Vote My Answer!!