# Is there a way to make a customView for battery?

Tags: android, battery

Is there a way to make a customView for the battery status?

Like i'm trying to make a kiosk app so the status bar is hided and i'm showing the wi-fi status with the following [library](https://github.com/MikeFot/Android--WiFi-ImageView), is there a way to make something for the battery or is there yet an existing library for it?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register broadcast receiver and get what you need in onReceive

```
val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val battery = intent?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0)
        }
        //todo
    }

registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
```