# Android get the device battery level accurate to decimal level

Tags: android, react-native

For Android application i need battery level accurate to the 2 decimal value. How can i get the battery level accurate to the two decimal value?

Comment: You can't. Android does not give you this information. But even if you could, the sensors used in batteries are not accurate enough to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get battery level and state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Since [API 21](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0) its been possible to use the following to get current battery level as a percentage:

```
BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager)getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
int batLevel = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
```

Alternatively, you can also use the following [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-battery) for getting the battery stats for Android:

```
import com.robinpowered.react.battery.DeviceBatteryPackage;  // <--- import 

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
  ......

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);

    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
      .setApplication(getApplication())
      .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
      .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
      .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
      .addPackage(new DeviceBatteryPackage()) // <------ add this line to yout MainActivity class 
      .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
      .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
      .build();

    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "AndroidRNSample", null);

    setContentView(mReactRootView);
  }

  ......

}
```

Or use this [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-battery) for getting Battery stats for both Android and iOS

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var BatteryManager = require('NativeModules').BatteryManager;
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  DeviceEventEmitter,
} = React;

var RCTBattery = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {batteryLevel: null, charging:false};
  },

  onBatteryStatus: function(info){
    this.setState({batteryLevel: info.level});
    this.setState({charging: info.isPlugged});
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    BatteryManager.updateBatteryLevel(function(info){
      this._subscription = DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('BatteryStatus', this.onBatteryStatus);
      this.setState({batteryLevel: info.level});
      this.setState({charging: info.isPlugged});
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this._subscription.remove();
  },

  render: function() {
    var chargingText;
    if(this.state.charging){
      chargingText =<Text style={styles.instructions}>Charging </Text>;
    } else {
      chargingText =<Text style={styles.instructions}>Not Charging </Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Battery Level {this.state.batteryLevel}
        </Text>
        {chargingText}
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RCTBattery', () => RCTBattery);
```

I hope this helps.