# How detect PowerSaveMode change in Android

Tags: android, battery, powermanager

I'm trying to detect the PowerSaveMode change for battery. 
I'm using the method pm.isPowerSaveMode(). The problem that i have always a false result. I'm trying to update the statut to enable but always the result is false. 
I'm using three differents devices, S8+ (Android 9) , One plus(Android 10), Sony (Android 10)...

Any solution please ?

Comment: Have you tried using [ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED)

Comment: It is the action that we need to use it to detect the change of statut ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get battery level and state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291655/get-battery-level-and-state-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

This is working fine in OnePlus(Android 10) and emulator(Android 10)

```
 PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
 boolean powerSaveMode = powerManager.isPowerSaveMode();
 Log.e("Power Saver", "Mode is " + powerSaveMode);
```